# Define array and add values using a loop

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

How define array and add values to a VARRAY using a loop?

```
Declare
TYPE code_array IS VARRAY(this is changeable) OF VARCHAR2(10);
begin    ​

  ​FOR i IN 1..APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01.COUNT LOOP  
           ​// How put i in code_array ?   i is 1, 2 ...
      ​END LOOP;
end;
```

Need this resault  eg.:  **('1','2','3','4','5')**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declared a local variable of type `code_array`, you could do something like this

```
Declare
  TYPE code_array IS VARRAY(5) OF VARCHAR2(10);
  l_codes code_array;
begin    ​

  ​FOR i IN 1..APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01.COUNT LOOP  
    l_codes(i) := to_char(i);
  ​END LOOP;
end;
```

If you are iterating from 1 to `apex_application.g_f01.count`, however, that strongly implies that the number of elements you want to handle is not known at compile time.  If that is the case, a `varray` is almost certainly the wrong type of collection to use (frankly, IMHO, `varray` is basically always the wrong type of collection to use).  You'd be much better off with a nested table or an associative array

```
Declare
  TYPE code_nt is table of varchar2(10);
  l_codes code_nt := code_nt();
begin    ​

  ​FOR i IN 1..APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01.COUNT LOOP  
    l_codes.extend;
    l_codes(i) := to_char(i);
  ​END LOOP;
end;
```

Comment: Nice example, is it possible put resault  nested table as parameter to procedure?

Comment: @user_odoo - Sure.  You'd just need the declaration of the type to be visible to both the caller and the callee.  I'd declare the type in SQL but you could also declare it in a package declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing my plsql function, it's quick and dirty done, it does what you asked, surely can be optimized.

```
FUNCTION AppendArrays(column_values1 IN varchar2_table,column_values2 IN varchar2_table) RETURN varchar2_table IS
        column_values_array Varchar2_Table; -- Try using DBMS_SQL.Varchar2_Table; 
    BEGIN
          column_values_array := column_values1;
          column_values_array.extend(column_values2.count);
          FOR i IN 1..(column_values2.count) LOOP    
            column_values_array(i+column_values2.count) := column_values2(i);
          END LOOP;
          return column_values_array;
END AppendArrays;
```

Also I have my own type but try using DBMS_SQL.Varchar2_Table instead.

```
create or replace TYPE VARCHAR2_TABLE AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(2000);
```